# How to FIX RAIN LEAKAGE

Tags: water, damage

Hello i have a problem when it rains the dirt and rocks stay wet and the foundation of the house is starting to leak. Does anyone know how to properly fix this and what exactly do i need to do? Here are some photos of what is going on[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the state of the gutter system? Is the water pooling around the foundation due to water landing on the roof and overflowing the gutter (or not landing in the gutter)?

Comment: I dont have a gutter system right now. What the problem is when it rains the ground stays wet and the ground is higher than my house foundation? So do i need to dig a trench or something? And use some kind of sealant ?>

Comment: Gutters are used for two main reasons, the most notable is to direct water away from where you dont want it. The other is built off the first one, but its cleanliness, because water dropping from 10' or more above onto the ground splashes mud onto the surrounding area, and also erodes the ground level causing the issues you have. There are a number of solutions, but the biggest one to start with is to add gutters. The second is to grade/regrade the land to pull water away from the house. The 3ed is to install drain tiles in the area trapping water.

Comment: A good gutter is better than a trench because it catches and diverts the water away from the house *before* the water touches the foundation.

Comment: also from your photos, it looks like the stone meets the painted wood. This is not good for the wood because it is leeching water from the ground like a sponge. That is why many buildings by code are put on slabs/foundations of cement above ground level. If your slab has sunk/settled, this is promoting water entry into the building.

Comment: If the stones are banked up then drag them clear of the lower wall.  That alone might help create the vertical gap needed.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=110730496667499&set=a.105479243859291&type=3&theater

Comment: this is what i have done

Comment: anything else you would recommend?